# How to debug/unit test webAPi in one solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to unit test or debug a web api in one vs solution?  I am consuming the WebAPI using HttpClient and have two instances of VS up to do this.

in 1 VS instance I have the unit test, in the second vs instance I have the webapi running in localhost.

Is there a better way to do this?

Is the preferred way to unit test is to have a reference to the WebAPI project?

I want to consume it using httpClient and not have to reference it in the UnitTest Project.

so in my UnitTest method it would have a baseAddress of "http://localhost:1234"

this would be where the WebAPI if launched from the same solution would be hosted.

The current way I am debugging requires me to launch a second Visual Studio instance with the same solution loaded and have one running the WebAPI project, while the other Visual Studio runs the Unit Test project.

Comment: If your tests are accessing the web API as a web API, they aren't unit tests, they're integration tests. Your tests rely on the API being correctly deployed and configured in order to pass.

Comment: You should be able to self host the web api from within the test code.

Comment: by Unit test in mean running the Unit Test project in VS studio. With WCF projects I can run/execute the unit test methods within 1 VS instance.  Thanks for your comment about the difference between testing concepts and definitions. But I wasn't talking about that.

Comment: Good tests interact with the exposed surface of your API, and should be ignorant of internal implementation details (which may change). Controllers, routing, and the rest of the WebApi stack are both implementation details, and largely not your code. Why go through all the contortions of mocking and instantiating all that when you can just run a server with a known recreatable data source?

Answer (score 19):

1. Start debugging Unit Test
2. While on the first line of your test code or before calling your local web api project
3. Right click on your web api project and Debug > Start new instance

Comment: Thanks this is the quickest and simplest workaround I found.

Answer (score 7):

So a colleague and I just tried the suggested answers to no avail. However, we have actually found a solution to this that works well by attaching to the IIS process once you are in debug mode on your test. Here are the steps:

1. Ensure your unit-test project and Web API project are in the same solution.
2. Ensure your solution is set  single-startup in the properties section (i.e. leave as default).
3. Add a breakpoint to the endpoint in your controller method that you want to debug.
4. Add a breakpoint in your test that you want to debug and then right-click and hit "Debug Tests" (or use your favorite Test Runner like ReSharper to debug).
5. Once your break point hits, click Debug | Attach to Process...
6. Find and click on your local IIS process for the given service, then hit Attach
7. Continue debugging and watch your breakpoint in your service get hit

For extra ease, we downloaded an extension for attaching to IIS automatically which gave us a menubar item in the Tools menu.

For superb ease we customized the toolbar section to add the menubar command to the toolbar so that attaching to IIS was one simple click.

Answer (score 4):

As Daniel Mann stated, this isn't unit testing.  This is integration testing.  You are running up the entire project and testing everything.

If you want to unit test you webapi controllers, just add a unit test project to webapi project and create unit tests.  You want to focus on testing only a single class at a time. Mock/Fake any dependencies of that class.

Here's a nice example from Microsoft http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api

but if what you are looking for is running the test you have in a single solution.  Just put both projects in the same solution.  Right click on the solution in the solution explorer.  Select "Set StartUp projects." select "multiple startup projects"  and select the projects you want to startup at the same time.

Comment: the last part is what I was looking for. I will have to try it out. I wasn't aware you can set multiple startup projects.  I wasn't clear on my original post.  I have a Unit Test Project and a WebAPi project in the same solution. I wasn't able to test it like how I was testing a WCF project (in the same solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can self host the web api as mike mentioned,

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}", 
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

for more details,
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api

you could start the hosting when you initialize your unit test suite, and shutdown when you cleanup the test suite.

Comment: in a selfHosted situation, can you debug the WebAPI project?

Comment: How is this hosting his API project? You just defined an HTTP server at "http://localhost:8080". Where is his API project referenced?

Comment: a few problems with this solution because self hosted has different logic in some places for example 'HttpContext.Current' is null by self hosted, problem with custom error handler

Answer (score 0):

If you have an API project and you created an end-to-end unit test project for the API (meaning you are testing the API directly using HttpClient, WebClient, or other http client wrappers), you have to enable "Multiple startup projects" on the solution. Follow steps below:

1. Right click on the solution file and select properties.
2. Select "Multiple startup projects" radio button.
3. Select the "Start" action in the drop-down for the web api project and unit test project.
4. F5 to start in debug mode.
5. You will get an error dialog saying "A project with an output type class library cannot be started directly". This is fine since the unit test project is just a class library (not an executable so there is no main/start method). Just click "Ok" the dialog.
6. On the unit test method you want to test, right click and select "Debug Unit Tests" to start debugging.

Comment: Works until step 5, but step 6 (executing/debugging unit tests) is not allowed when an application is running. Using VS2015

Comment: did you setup the solution as multiple startup projects? just select only the api as the startup then right click on test method and select debug test in context menu

Comment: Maybe I have a different setup, but I have one solution with 2 projects: 1 testproject, one api project. For both variants (multiple startup projects or single) starting the test (unit test runner) does not start the api project. The other way round: starting the api prevents me from starting unit tests.

Comment: Can right click on the solution (in Visual Studio) and select properties in context menu. You should see the startup options. Select the "Multiple Startup projects" and set the api project action to 'Start' and the test project to 'None'

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is what I have done already. The only practical solution (i do not want to attach to processes after pressing debug) for me is using a separate integration test solution.

Comment: You're welcome. It will still be an integration test because you are actually invoking via the API app (and not as a project reference) except that the projects are in one solution.

Comment: An important thing I missed for a while on the "Select Startup Projects" - "Multiple startup projects" form is that you can set the order in which the projects are started. Things tend to work better if the webapi is started before code in the other project tries to call it!

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of ASP.Net Core the official solution to this is to use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost Nuget assembly which creates a simulated web server hosting the web project in the test project.

Details on usage can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/testing/integration-testing

On the one hand it feels like a bit of a fudge because by what definition is it genuine integration testing if a real web server is not involved, on the other hand it does at least work pretty seamlessly once you get it set up.

Answer (score 0):

I try the selft hosted but I get some problens
1.

```
HttpContext.Current is null
```

2. I have in the web api custom error handler and in self hosted don't work

IisExpress solution work for me very good

bathe file to deploy to iis

```
@Echo off 
set msBuildDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
::compile web api project
call "%msBuildDir%\msbuild.exe" solutionFilePath.sln /t:projectName /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5 /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Manual_MSBuild_ReleaseVersion_LOG.log /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:"pathToRootOfApiProject" /port:8888 /trace:error
```

**I work with Nunit frameWork**

```
  [SetUpFixture]
    public class SetUpTest
    {
        private Process process = null;
        private Process IisProcess = null;
        private System.IO.StreamWriter sw = null;
        string programsFilePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"PROGRAMFILES(X86)");

        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            //compile web api project
            List<string> commands = new List<string>();
            commands.Add($@"CD {programsFilePath}\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\");
            commands.Add($@"msbuild ""pathToYourSolution.sln"" /t:ProjrctName /p:Configuration=Debug;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5 /p:Platform=""Any CPU"" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false /p:VSToolsPath=""{programsFilePath}\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0""");
            RunCommands(commands);

            //deploy to iis express
            RunIis();
        }



        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void OneTimeTearDown()
        {
            if (IisProcess.HasExited == false)
            {
                IisProcess.Kill();
            }
        }

        void RunCommands(List<string> cmds, string workingDirectory = "")
        {
            if (process == null)
            {
                InitializeCmd(workingDirectory);
                sw = process.StandardInput;
            }

            foreach (var cmd in cmds)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(cmd);
            }
        }

        void InitializeCmd(string workingDirectory = "")
        {
            process = new Process();
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            process.StartInfo = psi;
            process.Start();
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { Debug.WriteLine($"cmd output: {e.Data}"); };
            process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { Debug.WriteLine($"cmd output: {e.Data}"); throw new Exception(e.Data); };
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }

        void RunIis()
        {
            string _port = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["requiredPort"];
            if (_port == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("no value by config setting for 'requiredPort'");
            }

            IisProcess = new Process();
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.FileName = $@"{programsFilePath}\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe";
            psi.Arguments = $@"/path:""pathToRootOfApiProject"" /port:{_port} /trace:error";
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            IisProcess.StartInfo = psi;
            IisProcess.Start();
            IisProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { Debug.WriteLine($"cmd output: {e.Data}"); };
            IisProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"cmd output: {e.Data}");
                if (e.Data != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Data);
                }
            };
            IisProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            IisProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        }
    }
```

**attach to iisexpress**

Debug test then make a breakpoint 
goto Debug>Attach to process>
in the attach to select
[image]
click OK,

search iisexpress and click attach